# Add ons for product variables in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a site that sells coffee.  I have two variations for each coffee product. Variation 1: 12 oz size
Variation 2: 5 lb size

Once a user chooses a size I want them to be able to choose whole bean or one of seven grind levels.  The price of ground coffee will be .50 for variation 1 - 12 oz bags and 1.50 for variation 2 - 5 lb bags.

Is there a way to do this without creating a ton of variation combinations.  I'd like to have a global add on that will allow me to add a price depending on the variation selected.  All of the existing plugins that I've found will only let you add options on a product level, not let you add options to variations.  Why is that?

Comment: You can add global attributes to use on product variations.  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-product-taxonomies/#section-3

Comment: Sure, but not in the way I described above.